# Django form valid even if it doesn't exist in template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have multiple forms using a single submit button in my template with `prefix=name` using CrispyForms.

[Check if a form exists or is rendered in Template. Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577022/check-if-a-form-exists-or-is-rendered-in-template-django/48577207?noredirect=1#comment84151233_48577207)

I have the following code in my template

```
{% extends BASE_TEMPLATE %}
{%  load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}<h2>New Thread</h2>{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ threadForm|crispy }}
            {{ postForm|crispy }}
            {% if SHOW_WIKI %}
            {{ wikiFrom|crispy }}
            {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Note the `if` condition here. I know for sure that the form is not rendered in certain cases and the form is still valid

The only filed which the WikiForm renders has `blank=True`.

What happens when I do `wikiForm.is_valid()` in my code is even though it hasn't been shown in template it is valid according to Django.

Why does this happen?

Is there a way to fix this in a way other than making the field in my `wikiForm` to `blank=False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the form is there. Maybe a little typo in your template (if you've copied this directly from your machine),

`{{ wikiFrom|crispy }}`

When you use crispy forms, you are essentially using django forms with crispy layout. So, somewhere in your code you must have instantiated the actual form class, right there your form was created. It was just not rendered because of your conditions inside the template. Moreover, making a field `blank=True` allows form to consider the field valid if there is nothing in it. Had it been a required field and you had passed a blank string, the validation would fail.

Comment: There is a if condition which checks for `{{ if SHOW_WIKI }}` and shows the form only if that condition is met. However my form is not shown as I have set condition to `False` and it still verifies

Comment: Re read your statement. If the condition is satisfied, the form is not *shown*, but it is there. I'm updating my answer for clarification.